# How to subset a dataframe using unique groups and make plots using specific columns from each resulting data frame

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, time-series

I want to do the following

1. convert the `phase` column to time-series object 30 mins interval
2. subset the dataframe `df`  based on `group`. `df_A`, `df_B` and `df_C` (representing groups A, B and C)
3. plot phase.vs.count graph for each subset

```
group,phase, count
A, 0, 3000
A, 30, 3315
A, 60, 3690
A, 90, 4002
A, 120, 4210
B, 0, 2000
B, 30, 2100
B, 60, 2215
B, 90, 2303
B, 120, 2412
C, 0, 3001
C, 30, 3120
C, 60, 3225
C, 90, 3350
C, 120, 3459
```

My attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# 1. 
Not sure how it works in Python but in R,  I just use ts() function 

# 2 I exported the dataframes as .csv files (you can by pass exporting the dataframes )
groupx = df.groupby(["group"]).count().index
for group in groupx:
    df[(df["group"] == group[0])].to_csv(f"{group[0]}.csv") # 

#3 
files = [x for x in os.listdir("./") if os.path.splitext(x)[1] == ".csv"] # selecting the files 
with PdfPages('timeseriesPlot.pdf') as pdf: # preparing to display the figures in a pdf
    for i in range(0, len(files), 4): # maximum of 4 figures per pdf page
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2,figsize=(9,6))
        max_len = i + 4 if len(files) > i + 4 else len(files) # if more than 4 pages move to next page
        for ax, file in zip(axs.flatten(), files[i:max_len]):
            df = pd.read_csv(file)
            df_temp = df.iloc[:,1:2] # index for 'phase' and 'count' columns respectively
            count= df['count'][0] 
            phase = df['phase'][0]
            
            plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
            plt.plot(df)
            for minx in range(0,120): # time ranging from 0 to 120 minutes
                plt.axvline(datetime(minx,1,1), color='k', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5) # to detect anomalies

            ax.set_title(f"{Phase vs Count Group}") # for groups A, B and C
            ax.set_xlabel('Phase')
            ax.set_ylabel('count')
            plt.tight_layout()
            ax.legend(loc='best') 
        pdf.savefig(fig, dpi = 300)
```

Thanks for the effort

Comment: you code's comment says _Not sure how it works in Python but in R,  I just use ts() function_ What does this mean? What does the `ts` function do and why do you use it?

Comment: @PaulH  ts() function will convert a numeric vector into an R time series object.